# Connecting Google Cloud SQL with Wordpress on Google Compute Engine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

I've been running a successful Wordpress install on Google Compute Engine with Nginx, Php-fpm and Mysql.

I noticed you can also run Wordpress on App Engine with a Cloud SQL connection as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress?hl=en

I want to use Wordpress on Compute Engine with the db running on Cloud SQL.

On AppEngine, you need to put the following lines in the wp-config.php file

```
if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App      Engine') !== false) {
  define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/YOUR_PROJECT_ID:wordpress_db_name');F
}else{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
}
```

Is there a similar way to connect Wordpress on Compute Engine with Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no need to connect to fancy socket names, you need to set up Wordpress as a [usual MySQL client](http://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/gce-access), just keep in mind that you need to [pre-authorize](http://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control) Compute Engine instance to access your Cloud SQL instance.