# secure https with wordpress on google compute engine , cloud sql proxy and cloud SQL

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-compute-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

I am setting up a ecommerce site with following configuration.
1. wordpress on ubuntu on google compute engine VM
2. Database on Cloud SQL in the same google cloud project.
Wordpress connects to localhost and is routed to cloud SQL through cloud proxy. It is setup with service account.
I am using letsencrypt SSL certificate on the VM. With this, I am getting secure http:// on browser only for wp-admin session. I get info https level only, for the user sessions.

I tried SSL, using wordpress "secure db connection" plugin on top of the cloud proxy. It does not connect. Without this SSL, it gives me only info https level.

Please let me know the following:
Is the above configuration (cloud sql proxy for connecting to DB instance. And wordpress on VM with SSL) sufficient ? Is the problem in something else?

anyone successfully did cloud sql proxy with SSL ? or any other way to resolve info https problem?

Comment: Why do you want to add SSL over Cloud SQL proxy? it is not an [advisable](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#what_the_proxy_provides) approach to use [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy) along with the SSL. When we use the Cloud SQL Proxy, it already provides a secure access to your Cloud SQL Second Generation instances without having to [whitelist IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip) or [configure SSL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance).

Comment: Since you are going to use a WP site which would ultimately have a ‘static IP’ of its own. So,  you can directly [connect](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip) this IP address to a Cloud SQL by adding this to the authorized networks of the Cloud SQL instance.Then you can  further use your [SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl) to connect your Cloud SQL instance as well.

Comment: Additionally, you might also need to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059821/connecting-google-cloud-sql-with-wordpress-on-google-compute-engine) discussion about connecting 'Wordpress on Compute Engine with cloud SQL' as well